# External JavaScript that returns the date

Tags: javascript, html

How can I turn this script:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

To an external JS file that will just show the date, when I will call the script on my html pages, when they load?

Comment: Just slap the JS in an external file and load it before the closing body element.

Comment: @Nitzan Goodman Where is your question?

Comment: Sorry first question I'm asking here and I had hard time posting the code. I figured it tho, thank you

Comment: @NitzanGoodman Please answer your own question then, it could be helpful to other people. You're encouraged to do that here

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src='my_script.js'></script>
```

my_script.js

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
```

or better:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(Date());
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(textNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the functionality in a function that you can call and it will populate an element accordingly.

**External JS (loaded in the head element, or at the foot of the page)**

```
function populateDate(elementId) {
    if (elementId) {
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = new Date();
    }
}
```

And call it via...

```
<script>
    populateDate('someElementIdOnYourPage');
</script>
```

Or via an event handler e.g.

```
<button onclick="populateDate('someElement');">Click me</button>
```

... on your HTML pages.

Comment: No need for `new Date()` since `Date()` will return a string when called without `new` and an instance of  `Date` will return a string when `.toString()` is called, that makes `(new Date()).toString()` and `Date()` practical the same. And`.toString` is called when the instance is used in a string context.

Comment: Yes, fair point. I come from an OO perspective, so it's force of habit, I guess :)

Comment: It is interesting as JS is oo and you don't need to use the new keyword. JS is cool like that